# Dynamically changing slides based off user input in Powerpoint

Tags: javascript, ms-office, powerpoint, powerpoint-2013, office-js

I am hoping to create a PowerPoint that will enable me to check off a few boxes on the introductory slide which will then determine what a chart will look like on a slide later on in the presentation. Is this possible to do in Powerpoint only or would I need to put the check boxes in Excel and show/hide information in that program, then link the powerpoint chart to this sheet?

Alternatively, is there a way for me to insert some sort of Javascript into Powerpoint which will show/hide sections of the chart based off a user input?

Thanks for your input :p

Comment: You can use Visual Basic to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at [Office Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220060.aspx). Essentially, Office Add-Ins are web applications embedded inside Office with APIs that allow interaction with the current document/application. Sounds like exactly what you need.

Gabriel Royer

Developer on the Office Extensibility Team, MSFT

Comment: we are looking at the add-ins capabilities daily, is there any place where we can learn more about the API roadmap or give feedback?

Comment: @Cilvic. Gab's reply is misleading: there is currently no "web add-in" API for PowerPoint that will help you. There are currently only APIs for Word and for Excel. You can give feedback here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.

Comment: @CindyMeister - I beg your pardon, but you can in fact have both content and task pane add-ins in PowerPoint as detailed here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn833104.aspx. While we don't have updated API surface for PowerPoint yet, you can still use all of Office JS apis inside PowerPoint add-ins.

Comment: @Gab. Sorry, I was mistaken in the capabilities available for PowerPoint. But I still find your reply misleading as it's not accurate for versions earlier than 2013.
user80648: However,  if you're not targeting Office 2013 or later OR the intention is to manipulate the slide content (change the chart) and the chart is embedded in the presentation (not in an outside workbook) the currently available JS APIs can't help.

Comment: @gab i agree that the current APIs dont help at all with the question. Hence my inquiry about a roadmap. Any links there?

Comment: @clivic - I'm sorry, we don't have a public roadmap except for what's on this page : https://dev.office.com/blogs/Office-js-Public-Preview